# Viewing/analyze all database accesses in Django

Tags: mysql, database, django

Is there a way to print or log all database accesses as they occur in Django?

This would be helpful for optimizing database accesses.  It would also be nice to see the actual query being executed.

I will be testing this using a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way would be to use https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar :)

You can track all the queries, signals, etc..

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like what I need.  I'll try to get it running now.